# What is the explanation of the odd even effect in liquid crystals?

Tags: organic-chemistry, thermodynamics, temperature, reference-request, liquid-crystals

What is the most accepted theory for explaining the *odd even effect* in liquid crystals? Can anyone explain and refer the corresponding paper?

Comment: Do you have access to a literature search tool like e.g. SciFinder, ISI Web of Science, or even Google Scholar? Have you already done some searching using any of those methods?

Comment: I hope you mean liquid crystals with `LC`. I also added the reference request to the question, if I introduced any mistakes, please [edit] yourself.

Comment: I have been busy in going through more and more about main chain LC and did not search rigorously. But I did search about odd even effect but did'nt get any good results. Searched in Google. I will try to look whether my Institute has SciFinder access or not